# Django form passing key to next form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I want to pass a pk from one form to another so that it can be used as the foreign key for the second form. Here are the model:

**models.py**

```
  class CompanyDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CompanyDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyDetails

class DataRequest(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyDetails, default="0")
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class DataRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataRequest
        exclude = ['company']
```

And here is the view for the first form:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyDetailsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('canareeform:datarequest',  data.id))
    else:
        form = CompanyDetailsForm()
    return render(request, 'canareeform/index.html', {'form': form})
```

How should I set up my second view so that the form will save an object that has the foreign key for the object created by the first form in it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by passing the primary key of the first object through the url. It goes abc.com/form -> abc.com/form/16/datarequest.  Not super ideal since by changing the number in the url the second object will use some other foreign key.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyDetailsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('canareeform:datarequest',  args=(data.id,)))
    else:
        form = CompanyDetailsForm()
    return render(request, 'canareeform/index.html', {'form': form})

def datarequest(request, company_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataRequestForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.company = CompanyDetails.objects.get(pk=company_id)
            data.save()
            return HttpResponse("Thanks")
    else:
        form = DataRequestForm()
    return render(request, 'canareeform/datarequest.html', {'form': form})
```

If anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear it.